# Should the height property be applied to table row groups?

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-tables

I came across another difference between the browsers, namely in how they handle `height` on the `tbody` element.

```html
<table>
 <tbody style="height:150px">
  <tr>
   <td style="border:1px solid">This is a test</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Chrome ignores the height, FF and IE11 do not.

So, which ones have got it right? I searched, but I found no authoritative answers.

[Visual formatting model details](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property) says of `height`

> Applies to: all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table columns, and column groups

with no further restrictions, but [W3C: Tables](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout) says

> CSS 2.1 does not define the meaning of 'height' on row groups

(where row groups are the thead, tbody and tfoot elements.) So is this simply a grey area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is this simply a grey area?

The propdef implies that `height` does apply to row groups, but exactly what effect it has is left undefined. A property that applies doesn't always need to have a tangible effect on layout; it might do nothing in some circumstances. Whether doing nothing in *all* circumstances, as is the case with Gecko et al, is a valid interpretation is probably up for debate. The point the spec is making is that whether a UA conforms to CSS2 is not affected by how it chooses to treat `height` on row groups. So my answer to that question is "probably."

Having said that, the behavior remains undefined as of css-tables-3, which is still in development, although [the resolution appears to be to match Firefox's behavior](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Nov/0069.html) (see [this issue](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/476)).

As the behavior is currently not interoperable, authors should not rely on using `height` with row groups.

Comment: Thanks. I'd restricted my searches to the w3.org and whatwg.org domains (because not interested in vendor-biased answers) so I missed this one. And yes, they do say "RESOLVED: Specify gecko's behavior for height on table-row-group", so I'll guess that will make it into the official spec one day.